# B1/B2 visa for visit

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I am holding b1/b2 visa, I have already visited us on business , can I go to US on travel us for attend my friends marriage.

Answer (score 2):

If

1. you have M under Entries meaning a multiple entry visa.
2. Expiration date is on or later than the date when you plan to present yourself at the border of the United States asking for admission (doesn't need to be valid during the trip only on the day of entry).
3. Under Type/Class you have B1/B2.

then the answer is yes. All of these need to be met.